# Jmockit: Verify call method of interface field

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

Version of JMockit that was used: 1.21
I have interface like this.
TestInterface:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    boolean callMethod();
}
```

A TestClass have field is a instance of that interface
TestClass:

```
public class TestClass {
    private final TestInterface inner = new TestInterface() {
        @Override
        public boolean callMethod() {
            subMethod();
            return false;
        }
    };
        public void subMethod() { System.out.println("Sub method");
    };
}
```

I try to verify calling method by fake an interfacein this tutorial.
http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#interfacesd

Test method.

```
public class TestInterfaceTest {
    TestClass sut;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        sut = Deencapsulation.newInstance(TestClass.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void mockAllClassesImplementingAnInterface() {

        TestInterface testInterface = new MockUp<TestInterface>() {
            @Mock
            public boolean callMethod(Invocation inv) {
                inv.proceed(); // throw exception here -> Will my expected method  be called here?
                return true;
            }
        }.getMockInstance();

        Deencapsulation.setField(sut, "INTER", testInterface);

        new NonStrictExpectations() {
            {
                Deencapsulation.invoke(sut, "subMethod");
            }
        };

        Boolean result = Deencapsulation.invoke(Deencapsulation.getField(sut, "INTER"), "callMethod");

        assertTrue(result);

        new Verifications() {
            {
                Deencapsulation.invoke(sut, "subMethod"); times = 1;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name
>   "ndroid.examples.helloandroid.$Impl_TestInterface" found

If you guys don't mind, could you please tell me how to resolve this byg. Many thanks.

Comment: Once I fixed the errors in your "sample code" (*please* make sure your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) compiles and runs!), everything worked fine and I did not see this error. You'll have to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Thanks @dcsohl for your confirm. Current , I'm implementing on version 1.21, it will throw that error.
Not only version 1.21, but version 1.29 also throws that exception. :D
What version did you use to reproduce my error?

Comment: I test on Android Studio :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, in my reevaluation of this issue, would seem to lie in the line `inv.proceed()`. You can't have that line in a `Mockup` of an interface.

`Invocation.proceed()` is intended when you want the `MockUp` implementation to proceed into the real code. But because you are mocking up an interface, *there is no real code*. You may think there is because your implementation of `TestClass` has an anonymous implementation of the interface, but the `MockUp` knows nothing of that anonymous class; it's doing a mockup of the interface and not of your anonymous implementation.

If you get rid of that line, the call to `Invocation.proceed()`, I think you'll find your error goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your kind helping. So we have no idea to verify an anonymous method?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said you couldn't proceed into it. You can mock it and verify it's being called, though.

Comment: I mean that we couldn't process into that class and verify that subMehod was called inside actual method. Is that right? Many thanks for kind support.

Comment: It all depends on what you *really* want to test. You can't mock up the anonymous class or actually test that it gets called ... but you *can* quite easily verify that it does what it's supposed to. In this case, you can verify that `subMethod()` gets called. You will have to do this with [partial mocking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial) of `sut`, and you should question whether you really want to do this, but you definitely can.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I didn't expect that it's as simple as that. I often use partial mocking of sut to verify.
You save my life. Thanks you again.
I will describe code which works for me in below.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the guidance of @dcsohl. The code below works for me.

```
    @Test
    public void mockAllClassesImplementingAnInterface() {
        // Partial mocking
        new NonStrictExpectations(sut) {
            {
                sut.subMethod();
            }
        };

        // Actual invocation
        Deencapsulation.invoke(Deencapsulation.getField(sut, "inner"), "callMethod");
        // Verify
        new Verifications() {
            {
                Deencapsulation.invoke(sut, "subMethod");
                times = 1;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I am afraid this test is full of mistakes (should not use `Deencapsulation.invoke`, for one). But more important, the whole thing (test + code to be tested) seems meaningless... A proper test is supposed to verify some meaningful and externally observable behavior.